# Issue with datacontext in datatemplate

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `ContentControl` which has a set of Triggers, which will be fired when the `Content` Property of the ContentControl, hits one of the Style.Triggers

```
   <ContentControl  Content="{Binding SelectedSearchQueryParameter.DataType}" Grid.Row="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Height="25"  MaxWidth="200">
     <ContentControl.Style>
           <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource TextBoxTemplate}" />
                   <Style.Triggers>
                      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedSearchQueryParameter.DataType}" Value="{x:Type sys:DateTime}">
                         <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource DateTimeTemplate}" />
                      </DataTrigger>
                   </Style.Triggers>
           </Style>
      </ContentControl.Style>
    </ContentControl>
```

This ContentControl works as expect, it will switch between a `TextBox` and a custom made `UserControl`. The issue is that I'm unable to bind to a property in my ViewModel to the Property `Text` in the `TextBox` defined in the `DataTemplate`

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TextBoxTemplate">
   <StackPanel>
     <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="200" Text="{Binding SearchQuery, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"/>
   </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

I've also tried to explicity set the DataContext to my viewmodel on the stackpanel, with no luck either.

I've tested the binding outside of the `ResourceDictionary`, and it works as expected.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try `Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.SearchQuery, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"`?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.SearchQuery, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"
```

Comment: What does DataContext refer to? Does the compiler understand this event without specifying the context in xaml?

Comment: @TobiasMoeThorstensen, `SearchQuery` is a property of your Window's `DataContext` not a property of the `Window`

Comment: The Binding Error is gone from the output window, but the setter of the property does not trigger..

Comment: @TobiasMoeThorstensen Do you raise notification when your DataType property is changed? I created similar datatrigger and it works.

Comment: @user2250152 Yes. I solved it this way: DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContentControl}}, Path=DataContext}